# Using ENTER key instead of clicking "SEARCH" button

Tags: form-submit, enter

I am not an IT person at all. But I do have some questions. I have always been able to move through screens at work using the ENTER key. But somehow a setting may have been changed and I can no longer use ENTER and have to actually click the buttons. Does anyone know how to change this back? Thanks!